# How do you get moon bow gems?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

How do you get moon bow gems??

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These are dropped by the monsters that appear in *Irregular Encounters* in the Rampage mode. You can only earn the gems in Hard and Very Hard.

The irregular encounters feature Crystal Rbbits instead of the creatures you would have fought, and it also says *Irregular* across the screen at the battle start.

The irregular battles happen randomly in place of the second battle and can happen on any non-boss stage.